# Polling for received messages in Slack

Tags: javascript, slack

We've just started using Slack and I've been looking for a feature that I liked about our previous chat program.

My previous chat client opened whenever I received a message and came to the front. Since (correct me if I'm worng) Slack doesn't have this feature, I was hoping to inject it myself, just like I did with a theme.

To add a theme, I had to edit `%slack%\app-3.2.0\resources\app.asar.unpacked\src\static\ssb-interop.js`

To achieve what I want, I came across the function `im.open()` which will open a direct message to a certain user. In the below pseudo-code I'll give an idea of what I had in mind.

```
// If a message is received...
if (im.messageReceived) {
    // Get the received message
    var message = im.message;

    // Open the slack client with a direct message to the
    // user I received the message from
    im.open(message.token, message.user);
}
```

Is something like this possible? And how would I go about doing this?